# Why is rsync adding an extra directory?

Tags: rsync

I was running

```
rsync -rv /home/myname/mydir1 myhost:/home/myname/mydir1
```

and got

```
/home/mydir1/mydir1/...
```

How do I fix this so i don't have a redundant "mydir1"?

Answer (score 3):

See the examples in the Usage section of the [rsync man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

You can use

```
rsync -rv /home/myname/mydir1 myhost:/home/myname
```

or

```
rsync -rv /home/myname/mydir1/ myhost:/home/myname/mydir1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -rv /home/myname/mydir1/* myhost:/home/myname/mydir1
```

will copy files under mydir1 only  (& subdirs)

```
rsync -rv /home/myname/mydir1 myhost:/home/myname/mydir1
```

will copy the directory itself so you get mydir1/mydir1

```
    francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ rm -rf b
    francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ mkdir b
    francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ rsync -rv a/* b
    sending incremental file list
    a

    sent 80 bytes  received 35 bytes  230.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
    francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ tree b
    b
    └── a

    0 directories, 1 file


 francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ rm -rf b
    francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ rsync -rv a b
    sending incremental file list
    created directory b
    a/
    a/a

    sent 108 bytes  received 63 bytes  342.00 bytes/sec
    total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
    francois@zaphod:~/tmp$ tree b
    b
    └── a
        └── a

    1 directory, 1 file
```

Comment: I think `rsync -rv /home/myname/mydir1/ myhost:/home/myname/mydir1/` should also do the trick, no need for a wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rare occasion where the trailing `/` is important.  In many commands specifying `foo` and `foo/` is identical.  But it does have a symantic difference. 
 In some commands, including rsync, the trailing `/` tells the command to take special action based on the fact this is a directory.  If you have a situation created by ...

```
mkdir foo bar
touch foo/baz
```

... and you want to copy the contents from foo to bar then DON'T specify ...

```
rsync -rv foo bar
```

... instead specify ...

```
rsync -rv foo/ bar
```

Otherwise rsync will believe you want the whole tree (including parent directory) copying into the target directory as you have found.

---

Another example with similar *effective* semantics is `ls` when listing links:

```
mkdir foo
touch foo/baz
ln -s foo bar

ls -l bar
lrwxrwxrwx 1 philip philip 3 May  7 14:58 bar -> foo

ls -l bar/
total 0
-rw-r----- 1 philip philip 0 May  7 14:58 baz
```